# Why need add another dot in section name

Tags: linux, kernel

Linux kernel:
commit 3d9a854c2dac3e888393b23ba7adafcce4d6d4b9
Date:   Sat Feb 20 01:03:43 2010 +0100

```
Rename .data[.percpu][.XXX] to .data[..percpu][..XXX].
```

Comment: What is your question? What that commit changed? Why it was done? This may be a better question for the linux kernel mailing list. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Robert for reminder.
Found the answer in the mailing list
http://www.uwsg.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1002.2/01728.html

> The problem is that with -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections gcc
> creates sections like .text.head and .data.nosave
> whenever someone has innocuous code like this:
> static void head(...) {...}
> or this:
> static int nosave = 1;
> somewhere in the kernel. Currently, kernel linker scripts
> are confused by such names and put these sections in wrong places.